# Python-style object library for Clojure

Tags: python, object-oriented, clojure, framework

## Background

I am authoring [`pulley.objective`](https://github.com/positronic-solutions/pulley.objective), an Open Source library that provides an object system inspired by Python's object model.  I have some features implemented, and would appreciate feedback before I continue.

Ultimate goals include:

- Support for calculated properties
- Allow methods to be attached to an object and invoked

  - A method differs from a function in that a method has access to the object on which the method was invoked
- Objects are (mostly) compatible with Clojure's persistent map objects.
- Inheritance, with Python-style MRO and access to `super`

The first two are currently implemented, and the third (map compatibility) is partially implemented.  The rest (inheritance, etc.) will be implemented in the future.

## Code

The code here is from revision [4ff7e05d1ed3dcd9c3d2642bd13f506809259a3b](https://github.com/positronic-solutions/pulley.objective/tree/4ff7e05d1ed3dcd9c3d2642bd13f506809259a3b).  Although I'm only posting the code here, feel free to comment on anything in the repository, such as documentation.

All the code is contained in [`src/com/positronic_solutions/pulley/objective.clj`](https://github.com/positronic-solutions/pulley.objective/blob/4ff7e05d1ed3dcd9c3d2642bd13f506809259a3b/src/com/positronic_solutions/pulley/objective.clj).

### Preliminaries

Here's the [namespace declaration](https://github.com/positronic-solutions/pulley.objective/blob/4ff7e05d1ed3dcd9c3d2642bd13f506809259a3b/src/com/positronic_solutions/pulley/objective.clj#L17) and a few preliminary declarations:

```
(ns com.positronic-solutions.pulley.objective)

(declare object-
         property-get-)
```

### `PersistentObject`

The [`PersistentObject`](https://github.com/positronic-solutions/pulley.objective/blob/4ff7e05d1ed3dcd9c3d2642bd13f506809259a3b/src/com/positronic_solutions/pulley/objective.clj#L22) type is responsible for implementing objects (I've elided most of the `invoke` variants here, since they're practically the same):

```
(deftype PersistentObject [attrs]
  clojure.lang.Associative
  (assoc [self k v]
    (object- (assoc attrs k v)))
  (cons [self entry]
    (let [[k v] entry]
      (assoc self k v)))
  (containsKey [self k]
    (contains? attrs k))
  (empty [self]
    (new PersistentObject (empty attrs)))
  (entryAt [self k]
    (. attrs (entryAt k)))
  (equiv [self other]
    (. attrs (equiv other)))
  (seq [self]
    (seq attrs))
  (valAt [self k]
    (get attrs k))
  (valAt [self k default]
    (get attrs k default))

  clojure.lang.Counted
  (count [self]
    (count attrs))

  clojure.lang.IFn
  (invoke [self k]
    (if (contains? self k)
      (-> (get self k)
          (property-get- self))
      (throw (new IllegalArgumentException (str "Attribute not found: " k)))))
  (invoke [self k arg]
    ((self k) arg))
  (invoke [self k arg1 arg2]
    ((self k) arg1 arg2))
  (invoke [self k arg1 arg2 arg3]
    ((self k) arg1 arg2 arg3))

        .
        .
        .

  (invoke [self k arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5 arg6 arg7 arg8 arg9 arg10 arg11 arg12 arg13 arg14 arg15 arg16 arg17 arg18 arg19]
    ((self k) arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5 arg6 arg7 arg8 arg9 arg10 arg11 arg12 arg13 arg14 arg15 arg16 arg17 arg18 arg19))
  (invoke [self k arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5 arg6 arg7 arg8 arg9 arg10 arg11 arg12 arg13 arg14 arg15 arg16 arg17 arg18 arg19 args]
    (apply (self k) arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5 arg6 arg7 arg8 arg9 arg10 arg11 arg12 arg13 arg14 arg15 arg16 arg17 arg18 arg19 args))
  (applyTo [self args]
    (clojure.lang.AFn/applyToHelper self args)))
```

The [`object-`](https://github.com/positronic-solutions/pulley.objective/blob/4ff7e05d1ed3dcd9c3d2642bd13f506809259a3b/src/com/positronic_solutions/pulley/objective.clj#L97) function provides a private "constructor" for `PersistentObject` objects:

```
(defn- object- [attrs]
  (new PersistentObject attrs))
```

[`map->object`](https://github.com/positronic-solutions/pulley.objective/blob/4ff7e05d1ed3dcd9c3d2642bd13f506809259a3b/src/com/positronic_solutions/pulley/objective.clj#L100) provides a public constructor:

```
(defn map->object [attrs]
  (object- attrs))
```

### Properties

The [`IProperty`](https://github.com/positronic-solutions/pulley.objective/blob/4ff7e05d1ed3dcd9c3d2642bd13f506809259a3b/src/com/positronic_solutions/pulley/objective.clj#L108) protocol is used to support properties.  Only getting properties is supported in this version.

```
(defprotocol ^:private IProperty
  (property-get- [self instance]))
```

By default, attributes can be seen as "properties" where the "getter" is the `identity`function.  So we [extend `IProperty` to `Object`](https://github.com/positronic-solutions/pulley.objective/blob/4ff7e05d1ed3dcd9c3d2642bd13f506809259a3b/src/com/positronic_solutions/pulley/objective.clj#L111) as:

```
(extend-protocol IProperty
  Object
  (property-get- [self instance]
    self))
```

This implementation will be used when a non-property attribute is accessed.

The [`property`](https://github.com/positronic-solutions/pulley.objective/blob/4ff7e05d1ed3dcd9c3d2642bd13f506809259a3b/src/com/positronic_solutions/pulley/objective.clj#L116) function is used to implement a property:

```
(defn property
  ([& {getter :get}]
    (reify IProperty
      (property-get- [self instance]
        (getter instance)))))
```

### Methods

Methods are implemented using properties.  The [`method*`](https://github.com/positronic-solutions/pulley.objective/blob/4ff7e05d1ed3dcd9c3d2642bd13f506809259a3b/src/com/positronic_solutions/pulley/objective.clj#L127) function wraps a function `f` as a `property` which "binds" `f` to the instance the property is on.  As with Python methods, `f` is expected to take an explicit `self` argument.

```
(defn method*
  ([f]
    (property :get (fn [instance]
                     (fn [& args]
                       (apply f instance args))))))
```

The [`method`](https://github.com/positronic-solutions/pulley.objective/blob/4ff7e05d1ed3dcd9c3d2642bd13f506809259a3b/src/com/positronic_solutions/pulley/objective.clj#L133) macro is provides some syntactic sugar for defining methods:

```
(defmacro method
  ([& forms]
    `(method* (fn ~@forms))))
```

### Example Use

Here's a simple example of creating and using an object.  Additional examples can be found in the project's [Readme](https://github.com/positronic-solutions/pulley.objective/blob/4ff7e05d1ed3dcd9c3d2642bd13f506809259a3b/Readme.org):

First, import the library:

```
(require '[com.positronic-solutions.pulley.objective :as objective])
```

Now, create an object:

```
(def foo (objective/map->object {;; "Normal" attribute
                                 ::x 5

                                 ;; Property that increments ::x
                                 ::inc (objective/property :get (fn [self]
                                                                  (update self ::x inc)))

                                 ;; Example method
                                 ;; Computes sum of xs + self's ::x
                                 ::sum (objective/method [self & xs]
                                         (reduce + (self ::x) xs))}))
```

Now we can use `foo` as follows:

```
(foo ::x) ;; => 5
((foo ::inc) ::x) ;; => 6
(foo ::inc ::x) ;; => 6
(foo ::inc ::inc ::x) ;; => 7
(foo ::sum 1 2 3) ;; => 11
(foo ::inc ::sum 1 2 3) ;; => 12
(foo ::inc ::inc ::sum 1 2 3) ;; => 13
```